# how to hide google signin clientid from others?

Tags: jsp, google-signin

I am trying to integrate google signin and eveything works fine.

I am using this link for integration.
[google-signin](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in)

But my client id is visibile from my jsp page.

I am using the below line in my jsp inorder for the google signin to work.

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="<clientid>">
```

how to hide my client id from others without breaking the signin feature.

technologies used are,
java,jsp,javascript,gradle,springboot.

Will it be a security issue showing the clientid?

Answer (score 4):

The client id is not sensitive, there is no need to hide it. A client id only works with the authorized https origins, and it can only be used on your site.

Comment: I upvoted your answer as it makes the answer to my actual question unnecessary. But it will be really nice if I can get the answer for my first question.